# python isdigit() is True for ④ but int() fails

Tags: python, unicode

What is the difference between  and ④?

```
>>> u''.isdigit()
True
>>> int(u'')
4
>>> u'④'.isdigit()
True
>> int(u'④')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '④'
```

Note: above is output on python3. On python last gives this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'decimal' codec can't encode character u'\u2463' in position 0: invalid decimal Unicode string
```

Comment: just because it looks like a number to us humans, doesn't mean it's actually a number as far as unicode and computers are concerned.

Comment: that's not so simple, why `isdigit()` returns `True` then?

Comment: `isdecimal` is False for ④